# using jquery setInterval with delegate or on function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, setinterval

I am trying to make a dynamic sample object for a card generator.
the goal here is using a jquery color picker inside an asp.net update panel to pick a color and the chosen color will appear on the card frame (a **`<div>`** object).
as I read in several posts, the only way to keep the refresh dynamic is by using a setInterval timer each 100 to update the color selected in the color picker, since the picker passes the color to a textbox, then the setInterval reads the info and updates the color of the card.
this is the code, which works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            var cant = $('input[id$="txtColorFuente"]').val().length;
            if (cant >= 6) {
                $('div[id$="divMarco"]').css("color", "#" + $('input[id$="txtColorFuente"]').val());
            }
            cant = $('input[id$="txtColorFondo"]').val().length;
            if (cant >= 6) {
                $('div[id$="divMarco"]').css("background-color", "#" + $('input[id$="txtColorFondo"]').val());
            }
        }, 100);
    });
```

The DOM goes like this:

```
MasterPage,
Body,
Content(inner page),
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
        <section class="AdminFormLeft">
            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" CssClass="message-error" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <ul>
                <li class="labelForm">Color de fondo<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtColorFondo" MaxLength="6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /></li>
                <li class="labelForm">Color de fuente<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtColorFuente" MaxLength="6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /></li>

            </ul>
        </section>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        //My triggers here
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This works fine, until the update panel refreshes, then is lost, because it's re-generated, so I have to use delegate() or on() functions, however all my tries has been in vain. ¿How can I implement delegates or on function on set interval function above? thanks!

Comment: That's false. A good color picker would call a callback once a color is chosen and then you can do whatever you need to do with the selected color. Checking every 100ms for a task like this it is just a waste of time

Comment: Could you please recomend me a color picker?